# Toolkit for Windows Mobile?

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, toolkit

Looking for a good toolkit for windows mobile development.

So far, I looked into the Resco toolkit and I'm not so impressed with it. Especially the databinding.

Anyother toolkit that is worth a try to have a rich user experience?

Comment: Link for Resco:  http://www.resco.net/developer/mobileformstoolkit/overview.aspx

Answer (score 2):

One item that has been invaluable for us is the [OpenNETCF](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework/tabid/65/Default.aspx) library, which provides some functionality that was dropped or missing from the compact framework.

Comment: what is your impresssion about the opennetcf ?